# *Simple* Parse Cloud Code query failure "TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined\n retrieve that info "

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've been trying to do something very simple for several hours now and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm simple trying to query the username of the first person from my Parse data set via Cloud Code, and then I want to bring that down to my iOS application. Despite all attempts it doesn't seem to be working.  Below you'll find my code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userName", function(request,response){

    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo("username", request.params.username)
    query.first({
        success: function(getUserName) {
            var userString = getUserName.get("username");
            response.success(userString);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
        });
    });





[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userName" withParameters:@{} block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error){
            NSLog(result);
        }
    }];
```

I should also not that I'm bot sure what to put in the Parameters section besides "username :"

EDIT: Further, when I try to deploy the Parse Cloud Code I get "TypeError: Cannot call method 'get' of undefined\n"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. My mistakes came from a poor understanding of Javascript.

The below cloud code got what I wanted.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("userName", function(request,response){
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username);
query.first({
    success: function(object) {
        var userString = request.params.username;
        response.success(userString);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
});
```

The mistake I was making was that I was trying to use the ".get" method on an object that didn't have access to the said method. The weird thing is I tried to do the same thing with `request.object.get("username")` but apparently the request object also doesn't have access to the .get method (confusing because the Parse documentation seems to indicate that it does in its examples). So doing the above in combination with rickerbh's objective-c code below got me the result I was looking for.

It would help if someone could post the nature of the .get method in relation to Parse's cloud code here. Cheers.

Comment: You are not using 'object' anywhere! You are just returning back the username of request?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your cloud code, you're expecting a `request.params.username` to contain a value that you can use to lookup in the `User` class, via the `username` column. I typically access attributes of the `params` object via a key (I'm not sure if this is required, I just know it works for me). Try changing

```
query.equalTo("username", request.params.username)
```

to

```
query.equalTo("username", request.params["username"]);
```

Then, you need to get that data into the cloud function. Your Objective-C code passes an empty parameter block in, so looking anything up there will result in a whole lot of nothing.  Change your `PFCloud` call to

```
[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"userName" withParameters:@{@"username": @"theusernameyouwanttolookup"} block:^(NSString *result, NSError *error) {
```

And hopefully you'll have some better luck.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited the above to include the 'get' error that I'm getting. I'm not sure if your suggestion works or not since the code isn't able to deploy.

Comment: Is your issue that it won't deploy, or that it won't execute? That error message looks like it's happening on execution, not deployment. Try correcting the query, fixing your Objective-C to pass in username, redeploying, and then run it again.

Comment: It won't execute. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Also, the code you suggested doesn't really change anything since Javascript accesses functions via periods and brackets if I recall correctly. And ultimately what I want to do is print the string of the first user I grab from my Parse data.

Comment: I did note that I'm not sure if the javascript changes are required... Have you tried the objective-c code I've supplied?