# Parse Cloud Code weird bug

Tags: android, ios, swift, parse-platform, cloud

I have created a parse cloud beforeSave trigger for the predefined class ParseInstallation in order to delete duplicate parse installations for the same user, kinda like what is on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/mbmc/ebe5b65bc4eb86904c78). My deployed cloud code is the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {
   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
   var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
   //PROBLEM: request.object.get("username") is undefined...
   query.equalTo("username", request.object.get("username"));
   query.first().then(function(duplicate) {
      if (typeof duplicate === "undefined") {
          console.log("Duplicate does not exist, New installation");
          response.success();
      } else {
          console.log("Duplicate exist..Trying to delete " + duplicate.id);
          duplicate.destroy().then(function(duplicate) {
              console.log("Successfully deleted duplicate");
              response.success();
          }, function() {
              console.log(error.code + " " + error.message);
              response.success();
          });

      }
   }, function(error) {
      console.warn(error.code + error.message);
      response.success();
   });
})
```

The problem, as it is commented inline on the code, is that the `request.object.get("username")` returns undefined. In fact, all the properties of `request.object` are undefined!

On my android client app I associate the ParseUser and also the username to the ParseInstallation object, as follows:

```
user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
        ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
        installation.put("username", username);
        installation.put("user", user);
        installation.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Parse installation was created successfully!");
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "An error occurred while saving Parse installation: " + e.toString());
                }
            }
        });

        //more code...

    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Signup error: " + e.getMessage());

        //more code...
    }
}
});
```

So, given the above, one would expect that, on the parse cloud, `request.object.get("username")` would return the actual user username and not undefined, correct??? (Btw, yes I have checked that the username variable on the android client code is not null nor empty!)

Why the hell `request.object` properties are all undefined???

How to get `username` from ParseInstallation on the cloud trigger then???

Also, did anyone experienced this problem from an IOS client app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28823188/simple-parse-cloud-code-query-failure-typeerror-cannot-call-method-get-of    this might help

Comment: Thanks @Larcerax, but I tried using request.params.username as in that post but request.params is also undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the username through the `request.user` object:

```
var User = request.user;
console.log(User.get("username"));

//or skip the first step:
console.log(request.user.get("username"));
```

Note you can also retrieve these values by calling the `attributes` property of the Parse.Object (typically bad practice):

```
console.log(request.user.attributes.username);
```